# jOrtho Spell Checker Works on Mac and Windows 8 but not Windows 7

Tags: java, swing

jOrtho is working fine when my Java Swing application runs on a Mac or Windows 8.  However, when it runs on Windows 7, errors are not flagged, but if the user right-clicks a word, there is a pop-up menu that has menu items for spelling and languages, but they are ghosted.

Below is my code. The variable text is a JTextArea.

```
SpellChecker.setUserDictionaryProvider( new FileUserDictionary() );

try {
    String path = "file://localhost/" 
                        + System.getProperty("user.dir") 
                            + "/src/net/alwb/tms/utils/dictionaries/dictionaries.cnf";
    URL url = new URL(path);
    SpellChecker.registerDictionaries(url, null );
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
SpellChecker.register( text );
```

Comment: Have you tried an [tag:embedded-resource], for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info), instead of a `URL`?

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I tried two things.  First, using getClass().getResource(path) to get the URL, with the dictionaries.cnf file being in a folder that is a child of the one containing the classes.  Next, I moved the dictionaries out of the subfolder, and put them right in the folder where the classes are.  Same result.  It works fine on Macs and Windows 8, but not on Windows 7.

Comment: I'm nonplussed; if `dictionaries.cnf` is a configuration file, you might check see if the line ending are compatible with Windows.